# How to train a customized transformer model with custom dataset formatting

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, transformer-model

I am making a custom transformer model that fits specific AI model for converting a user prompt into three differnt classes {"lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl3"}, every level goes to a a different decoder that converts each levle text to a seperate task to be done.
I decided to make the classification with a decoder, and takes the output of this decoder and passes it to the other decoders.
the user prompts should be a task to be done like "I Want to create a word doc and write in it an article about globalization and send it to mom in whatsapp as pdf file"
this prompt shuld be classified before it goes to the other decoders.

the problem is that after I made the dataset, the training process goes wrong and I searched a lot in a way to get the classified output but I found nothing.

in the dataset I have a pronpt and the result, then I converted it into the following format:

```py
{
    "prompt": "Open a music composition software and compose a short piece inspired by nature",
    "classification": {
        "lvl1": {
            "start": [
                321
            ],
            "sequence": [
                321,
                269,
                539,
                1131,
                419
            ],
            "text": "Open a music composition software"
        },
        "lvl2": {
            "start": [
                1013
            ],
            "sequence": [
                1013,
                269,
                493,
                877,
                1072,
                1003,
                1026
            ],
            "text": "compose a short piece inspired by nature"
        },
        "lvl3": {
            "start": [
                -1
            ],
            "sequence": [],
            "text": ""
        }
    }
}
```

"start" is the first word token
"sequence" is the sequence of tokens for the lvel text
"text" is the text that should I got as a classification

the input is the "prompt"
and the result should be the "classification"

the encoder takes all the "prompts"
but I don't How to give the decoder the "classifications"

encoder code

```py
class EncoderBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, dimension_model, num_heads, hidden_dimension, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(EncoderBlock, self).__init__()

        self.mhsa = MultiHeadSelfAttention(dimension_model, num_heads)
        self.ffn = feed_forward_network(dimension_model, hidden_dimension)

        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)

        self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
    
    def call(self, x, training, mask):
        mhsa_output, attention_weights = self.mhsa(x, x, x, mask)
        # drop out
        mhsa_output = self.dropout1(mhsa_output, training=training)
        # skip connection
        mhsa_output = self.layernorm1(x + mhsa_output)

        ffn_output = self.ffn(mhsa_output)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        output = self.layernorm2(mhsa_output + ffn_output)

        return output, attention_weights
class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_blocks, dimension_model, num_heads, hidden_dimension, src_vocab_size, max_seq_len, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()

        self.dimension_model = dimension_model
        self.max_sql_len = max_seq_len

        self.token_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(src_vocab_size, self.dimension_model)
        self.positonal_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_seq_len, self.dimension_model)

        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)

        self.blocks = [EncoderBlock(self.dimension_model, num_heads, hidden_dimension, dropout_rate)
                       for _ in range(num_blocks)]
    
    def call(self, input, training, mask):
        token_embeddings = self.token_embedding(input)

        num_pos = input.shape[0] * self.max_sql_len
        positional_index = np.resize(np.arange(self.max_sql_len), num_pos)
        positional_index = np.reshape(positional_index, input.shape)
        positional_embeddings = self.positonal_embedding(positional_index)

        x = self.dropout(token_embeddings + positional_embeddings, training=training)

        for block in self.blocks:
            x, weights = block(x, training, mask)
        
        return x, weights
```

decoder code

```py
class DecoderBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, hidden_dim, dropout_rate=0.1):
    super(DecoderBlock, self).__init__()

    self.mhsa1 = MultiHeadSelfAttention(d_model, num_heads)
    self.mhsa2 = MultiHeadSelfAttention(d_model, num_heads)

    self.ffn = feed_forward_network(d_model, hidden_dim)

    self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
    self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
    self.dropout3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)

    self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm3 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
  
  # Note the decoder block takes two masks. One for the first MHSA, another
  # for the second MHSA.
  def call(self, encoder_output, target, training, decoder_mask, memory_mask):
    mhsa_output1, attn_weights = self.mhsa1(target, target, target, decoder_mask)
    mhsa_output1 = self.dropout1(mhsa_output1, training=training)
    mhsa_output1 = self.layernorm1(mhsa_output1 + target)

    mhsa_output2, attn_weights = self.mhsa2(mhsa_output1, encoder_output, 
                                            encoder_output, 
                                            memory_mask)
    mhsa_output2 = self.dropout2(mhsa_output2, training=training)
    mhsa_output2 = self.layernorm2(mhsa_output2 + mhsa_output1)

    ffn_output = self.ffn(mhsa_output2)
    ffn_output = self.dropout3(ffn_output, training=training)
    output = self.layernorm3(ffn_output + mhsa_output2)

    return output, attn_weights
class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_blocks, d_model, num_heads, hidden_dim, target_vocab_size,
               max_seq_len, dropout_rate=0.1):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()

    self.d_model = d_model
    self.max_seq_len = max_seq_len

    self.token_embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(target_vocab_size, self.d_model)
    self.pos_embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_seq_len, self.d_model)

    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)

    self.blocks = [DecoderBlock(self.d_model, num_heads, hidden_dim, dropout_rate) for _ in range(num_blocks)]

  def call(self, encoder_output, target, training, decoder_mask, memory_mask):
    token_embeds = self.token_embed(target)

    # Generate position indices.
    num_pos = target.shape[0] * self.max_seq_len
    pos_idx = np.resize(np.arange(self.max_seq_len), num_pos)
    pos_idx = np.reshape(pos_idx, target.shape)

    pos_embeds = self.pos_embed(pos_idx)

    x = self.dropout(token_embeds + pos_embeds, training=training)

    for block in self.blocks:
      x, weights = block(encoder_output, x, training, decoder_mask, memory_mask)

    return x, weights
```

Comment: "the training process goes wrong" This does not say anything clear, what exactly goes wrong and why is it a programming question?

Comment: basiclly what happens that transformer model gives me dumb tokens not even close to any word tokens, it hives somtihng like thie "V V V V V V" and this is a token for a "summ" token which is not even in the prompt.
your question about why it is a programming question, the question is about a transfomer model and my problem is in the dataset format clearly, by I don't know how should I format it in a way that goes into the decoder, so I ask about a way to train a decoder, should I give a code sample for the decoder ?

Comment: Well you did not include any code or training part, so people will not be able to help you with that, specially reminding that this is a programming site, not a general ML one.

Comment: I updated my question, IK that the problem is in the decoder code, but the problem is that I don't know what should I do exactly